# Flutter: Show PDF cover image

Tags: android, pdf, flutter

I want to show the cover page of a `pdf`. But I don't know how to proceed. I have the URL of the pdf file and I want to display the front page like an image. I am using the pdf library but I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 3):

I was also looking for the same a few days ago and found solution for it.
You can use this package:https://pub.dev/packages/pdf_render

you can use it like this in your widget:

```dart
import 'package:pdf_render/pdf_render_widgets2.dart';

...

PdfDocumentLoader(
    assetName: 'assets/hello.pdf',
    filePath: 'path of the file in local storage',
    pageNumber: 1,
    pageBuilder: (context, textureBuilder, pageSize) => textureBuilder()
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the pdf_thumbnail [package](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf_thumbnail), it uses pdfx package to get every single page.

[Relevant line in the library.](https://github.com/mirkancal/pdf_thumbnail/blob/main/lib/src/pdf_thumbnail.dart#L99-L120)

```
 final page = await document.getPage(pageNumber);
        final pageImage = await page.render(
          width: page.width,
          height: page.height,
        );
        images[pageNumber] = pageImage!.bytes;
        await page.close();
```

Answer (score -2):

There is a sample Futter wrapper for a PDF SDK here https://github.com/PDFTron/pdftron-flutter. And a corresponding blog: https://www.pdftron.com/blog/flutter/build-a-document-viewer-in-flutter/